# How to increase or decrease image size Gridview?

Tags: android

How to increase the image size in these.These have silk to give image text with recyleview array.The grid size of these should be large.How to  grid size increase.

Example [image]

row_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin4"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:tint="@android:color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want this size

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am using **AndroidX** for **CardView**, but you can also use support library for this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

set it at Width and Height attributes of the image.

Comment: i will update layout how to increase grid size

Comment: Set the Height to 100dp and Width to 100dp. If you think the image still small increase the size of it by increasing the height and width of it.